# sudo yum repolist show repo not in /etc/yum.repo.d

Tags: yum, repository, spacewalk

I'm having a little issue with yum. I'm trying to install a package but i realised yum it’s pulling it from the wrong repo (let’s call it repoB)
(I have added my own repo(let’s call it repoA) in the yum.repo.d folder)

when I look inside the yum.repo.d I do not see that repoB…?

But when I run sudo yum repolist I can see that repoB listed.

My question is, where is located this repoB ? How can I remove it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you replace "let's call it" with your actual configuration?  And include the output of `yum repolist`, as well as a listing of files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, and ideally the content of your repository configuration files.  Feel free to obfuscate ip addresses if that makes you feel better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repos are either defined via .repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` or via plugins, which are usually defined via files in `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d`

If you run `yum repolist --noplugins` does your repo in question still show up?

If you want to know the URLs of the packages from your mistery repo, you can use `yumdownloader --urls packagename` to see the URLs. `yumdownloader` is contained in the package `yum-utils`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this with Spacewalk I assume you are using Spacewalk and this machine is registered to Spacewalk. Spacewalk client tools (yum-rhn-plugin) will create those repos dynamicaly.
You must log-in Spacewalk webUI and find the machine there and there are listed channels (which are basically repositories) associate with this machine and you can deselect them.
Other option is to manage those channels from this machine using rhn-channel(8) tool.